# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$country' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

How can I make the variable readable inside the path?

```
$country = 'en_PH';
$faker->addProvider(new Faker\Provider\$country\Address($faker));
```

solved thank you so much

solution:

```
$path = "Faker\\Provider\\$country\\Address";
$faker->addProvider(new $path($faker));
```

Comment: Use string concatenation like ```$path = "Faker\\Provider\\$country\\Address";``` and later call it like ```$faker->addProvider(new $path($faker));```

Comment: Thank you so much it solved my problem :)

Comment: @jadpefaQwasvi In case you found a solution, it would be fine to post that as an answer and accept your own answer, instead of editing the question.